# Why are the php SORT_ASC, SORT_DESC built-in constant values ​4 and 3 when outputting with echo?

Tags: php, built-in

in php

```
echo SORT_ASC . '<br>';
echo SORT_DESC . '<br>';
```

When outputting, echo SORT_ASC has a value of 4
When outputting, echo SORT_DESC shows a value of 3.

Since it is a constant provided by default in PHP, the values ​​4 and 3 would have come out.
Do you know why the numbers 4 and 3 appear?

If you look at the meaning of the word, you know that SORT_ASC is sorted in ascending order, but why is such a value?
I'm not sure if it's coming out, so I'm asking.

Even though I searched PHP DOCUMENT, there seems to be no content, so I ask if I can find out.

Comment: They are just constants used for sorting, the integer value is not important (unless you want to use alternative ways of calling the sort).  These values are used internally to flag what sort of sort to do - that's all.

Comment: The numeric values are meaningless, they're just underlying enumeration values. The meaning of the constant and what it's used for are the important thing. https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.constants.php